# how to remove + sign form link, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, hyperlink

Is there a chance to remove + signs that merges category name that consists of two words?

Generated link looks like :

```
http://localhost:3000/lv/products?category=Dakšu+iekrāvēji
```

Between Dakšu and iekrāvēji is the problem, can I just leave with empty space ?
 Like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/lv/products?category=Dakšu iekrāvēji
```

**UPDATE**

Inside view I have like this.

```
<%= link_to (categ.name), products_path(:category => categ.name)   %>
```

Routes

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|lv|ru/ do
   resources :products, :manufacturers, :categories, :news, :ActiveAdmin, :manufacturer_products, :about_us, :contacts, :services
  end
```

Tnx

Comment: How did you "generate" that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way that i use : create a hash of the variables and use the methods to_query and append it to the path.

```
x = { "a" => "check1+123","b" => "check2" }
x.to_query
```

"a=check1%2B123&b=check2" is returned and can be appended to the path.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Regex` like this, I think it should work

```
<% temp = link_to (categ.name), products_path(:category => categ.name)   %> 
<% temp.gsub!(/\+/," ") %>
<%= temp %>
```

what we have done is we will put the URL as a string in a temp variable and then replace the plus sign with a space character as you wanted. In the last step we have put that whole link again to the HTML.